# Digging through huge gziped log files

Tags: linux, command-line, logs

From time to time I need to dig through huge log files (several GB unpacked) to debug a specific error.

Now, vim is OK for browsing through the file, but when I need to find something in the file it's completely useless. Is there some tool that could index the log and allow me to search the file faster?

Ideally a command line tool.

EDIT: Just to clarify, tools like `ack` or `grep` aren't suitable since I need to examine the context of the matches and `-C`,`-A`,`-B` just aren't good enough. Plus `ack` and `grep` are still unusably slow.

Comment: Did you try `grep`?

Comment: @Bernhard I actually didn't measure `grep` vs. `vim` in terms of speed, but `grep` is really unsuitable for what I need to do with the files. I need more flexibility than the `-C` `-B` and `-A` options offer.

Comment: There are plenty of logfile handling tools around, have you looked at what your distribution offers in that area?

Comment: I've heard good things about [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/), although I have yet to try it myself. It purports to be "better than grep", according to the domain name.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Did you try `less`? Searching a file with less is by magnitudes faster compared to `vim` (even with LargeFile plugin). But I assume the file needs to fit into memory. Furthermore I doubt that it will be faster than `grep`.

Comment: @Marco Wow, it actually is much faster. This could probably be good enough. I will do some testing.

Comment: If you've got enough memory and you know you will be working across a particular file, you might be able to coerce the kernel into keeping all of it cached `fadvise` or `fallocate` http://code.google.com/p/linux-ftools/. but generally the kernel knows what it's doing

Comment: Can't help you with the problem at hand. I just would like to mention that this reads like you need to develop some logging strategies. Make your programs log to some logging daemon. Those can perform different actions based on what they are supposed to write to the log files. In your case you may think about duplicating errors into another logfile and with the timestamp you know when and where to look for in the full log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are really good log indexers that are a bit bigger than command line tool level. Commercially, [splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) is the big one and hard to beat. [Graylog2](http://graylog2.org/) is a nice open source implementation. Elasticsearch+Logstash are quite good too.

There is a fair bit of overhead to both setting them up to collect and running the collection server but once you have central log collection as a part of your system, they're great. Querying and reporting logs from multiple sources is the biggest benefit for multi tiered apps.

As for command line, if you can plug your logging into syslog, the [systemd](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) [journald](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-journald.service.html) implementation allows for indexing on a [number of fields](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.journal-fields.html) as items are logged. Not sure if that would be useful in text processing though, more for the metadata.

Not sure about any ad hoc command line tools, they would still have an extract/load/parse time penalty each time you load the file.

That being said, `less` does most of what I need in a single log file.

```
&pattern  grep pattern
/pattern  search forward
?pattern  search backward
shift-f   tail -f
```

the `tail` mode can take the previous pattern into consideration as well which is great for watching live logs

Answer (score 2):

Searching through a file with `less` might be an option. It does not require the files to fit into memory. And it's much faster compared to vim (even when the LargeFile plugin is used).

The downsides are: It will probably not beat `grep` from a performance standpoint. And most of the alternatives choke if the file size approaches the RAM size.

Comment: `less` doesn't require the file to fit into memory, it's made to page huge files. It would benefit from a large file cache though, as any non indexing utility would.