# I need a text editor to edit/visualize >10GB text files

Tags: text-processing, software-rec, editors

So as to vizualize, and hopefully edit, a very large text file, more than 10GBytes (a backup dump of whole database), I have tried using vim... it didn't behave very well.

I have also tried cat to at least visualize, and cat didn't not behave properly neither.

Are there tools for huge file editing ? Something that would view/edit by a limited group of lines without trying to load the rest, unless told to load a new group (really limited) of lines, and maybe the possibility to jump certain places thanks to a search utility.

Comment: The problem is, if you edit, and that edit changes the length of the file, it needs to be rewritten entirely. And that's never a graceful thing to do with such huge files.

Comment: Also, the best tool to edit a database is the database itself.

Comment: It doesn't help for the editing part, but to visualise `less` might be an option. Also see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/66298/12779

Comment: @Marco, `less` is a terrible idea, it will load the whole file into memory to be able to move around.

Comment: @vonbrand No. Less opens the file instantly and without loading it into RAM.

Comment: @Marco I have just tried less, it's perfect for vizualization, instantly !

Comment: Related: [How can I edit a large file in place?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1279/12779)

Comment: You might be able to do the first part (up to the editing) more quickly with `hadoop` by dividing the work up, but you might have to roll your own software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't help for the editing part, but to visualise `less` might be an option. The advantage is that `less` can read large files quickly because it does not require the file to fit into the RAM. This makes it a much better choice than `vim`, for instance.

Answer (score 3):

Tools like `sed(1)` were designed for this kind of task. If you need more control over the operations done line by line, perhaps something like Perl or Python is a better match to the job.

In any case, rummaging inside a 10GiB file will take a *long* time. Isn't it easier just to slurp it into the database manager, and massage it there?

Comment: well I admit, editing seems really a bad idea regarding to all comments. However I do need to visualize. I like your idea of Python, if no ready-made utility  does the trick.

Comment: I'm looking at sed syntax, but in my howto, they don't mention your sed(1). What do you mean by (1) ? My command line doesn't accept it.

Comment: @StephaneRolland, Unix notation, it is `sed` in secion 1 (user commands) of the manuals.

Comment: Mmh... my first tryings right now with `sed` have not been conclusive: I'm gonna go python. I'll feel much more at ease.

Comment: Well my first try with python has not been convincing too :-) with readlines() it made my system on the brink of collapse :-)

Comment: @StephaneRolland, the whole point of sed, perl or python is to be able to work with a few lines at a time, _not_ the complete file. You'd need some 32GiB RAM just to load that...